# Can't get AJAX or jQuery to work on dynamic select list in rails4

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, dynamic, html-select

I am new to Rails and AJAX with jQuery. My page has radio buttons where the user selects a server, based on this selection my 1st dropdown box 'dir_list' gets populated with top level directory paths, then based on this selection the 2nd dropdown box is populated with the files the users can select to run a test on.

I have the first select box working with the radio buttons.  I was able to do this without AJAX. :onchange I call a JavaScript function that is in my index page.  It reads the value, does some if/else logic and then renders the partial page for the dir_list with the correct local which was hard-coded from the if/else logic in the JavaScript. I can't do this for my second select box. It is dynamic and the value has to be passed through AJAX. I have been reading and trying examples for several days but the AJAX and jQuery I have implemented is not working. I believe there are some assumptions in the examples and I am missing something because I am new to this.

I am running in Rails4 so I cannot use the remote_function.  My application.js file has jQuery in it.

Here is the project/app/assets/javascripts/application.js file: (I have taken all jQuery/AJAX tests example code out.  It is back to initial state)  I should be able to do this without adding any new gems.

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

At this point I started to use form_tag and submit on change. It semi works but because I have a master form url call for button click I run into issues.

The second issue is how to interpolate the variable directory path for the files.  I will open another question for that issue and keep this one focused on how to use AJAX or jQuery.  I have read and tried many examples so can someone please tell me step by step what I need to do and the location for the file with code examples for my specific case?

Here is my contoller code: Index loads up.  Then when a 'validate file' button is pushed and evaluate_media method is called and loads the page back.  (This part all works.)   The file_dir is the part I have the form submit to repopulate the second select box calling.

```
require 'media_info'
require 'alias_generator'
require 'rexml/document'

class FileAliasValidatesController < ApplicationController
 def index
    @state = 'index'
    @file_alias_validate = FileAliasValidate.all
    @file_exists_flag = "U"  #U for Unknown or Undeterrmined.
    @radio_button_value = 'miniprod'
    @dir_path_choice = '/watchfolder/miniprod/hot'

  end

 def file_dir
    @dir_path_choice = params[:dir_list]
    render :partial => 'list_files', :locals => {:dir_path_choice => @dir_path_choice }
  end   

  def evaluate_media
     @state = 'post'
     @radio_button_value = params[:location]

     #Determine if file chosen has been saved to database yet.
     @stored_file = FileAliasValidate.where(:full_path => params[:filepath], :deleted_b => 0).first

     if @stored_file.present?
       @file_exists_flag = 'Y'
       @file_exists_msg = 'File Alias has been saved in application.'
     else
       @file_exists_flag = 'N'
       @file_exists_msg = 'File Alias has NOT been saved in application yet.'
     end

       #Store selected value for re-display on post.
       @selected_filepath = params[:filepath]
       @filepath = File.join(params[:filepath])  

       @media_xml = ::MediaInfo.call(@filepath)  #Filepath is sent in from the index html
       @alias_xml = ::AliasGenerator.call(@media_xml)

       @media_xml_for = ""
       @alias_xml_for = ""
       REXML::Document.new(@media_xml).write(@media_xml_for, 1)
       REXML::Document.new(@alias_xml).write(@alias_xml_for, 1)
       alias_parse_doc = ""
       media_parse_doc = ""
       alias_parse_doc = REXML::Document.new(@alias_xml)  
       media_parse_doc = REXML::Document.new(@media_xml) 


       #parse Alias XML Doc   
       @aliasgen_ver = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "/aliasGenerator vr=/text()") { |element| element }    
       @file_alias = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "*//alias/text()") { |element| element }
       @file_status = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "*//error/text()") { |element| element }
       @file_msg = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "*//error_m/text()") { |element| element }
       @msg_dtl1 = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "*//closestvideoalias/text()") { |element| element }
       @msg_dtl2 = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "*//closestaudioalias/text()") { |element| element }

       #parse Video Media Info XML Doc  
        @filepathname = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "*//Complete_name/text()") { |element| element }  
        @video_format = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Format/text()") { |element| element }
        @video_bitrate = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Bit_rate/text()") { |element| element }  
        @video_width = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Width/text()") { |element| element } 
        @video_height = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Height/text()") { |element| element }
        @video_aspectratio = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Display_aspect_ratio/text()") { |element| element } 
        @video_framerate = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Frame_rate/text()") { |element| element } 
        @video_scantype = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Scan_type/text()") { |element| element } 
        @video_scanorder = REXML::XPath.each(media_parse_doc, "//track[@type='Video']/Scan_order/text()") { |element| element }   

       render :action => :index
   end
end
```

Here is the index code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Alias Validation -- Content Planner One Off Tool</title>
</head> 
<h1>Alias File Validation</h1>
<p><%= link_to "Main Menu Page", mainpages_home_path %> <%= ', ' %> <%= link_to "Alias Home Page", alias_main_pages_home_path %> </p>   
<%= form_tag file_alias_validates_evaluate_media_url do %>
<p>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>File Information:</legend>    
    <div class="form_row">
        <label for="dir_location">Select File Location:</label>
        <br><%= radio_button_tag 'location', 'miniprod', checked = true, :onclick => "render_dir_partial();" %> MiniProd Watch Folder
        <%= radio_button_tag 'location', 'watch', checked = false, :onclick => "render_dir_partial();" %> Prod Watch Folder
        <%= radio_button_tag 'location', 'archive', checked = false, :onclick => "render_dir_partial();" %> Prod Archive Folder
        <%= radio_button_tag 'location', 'local', checked = false, :onclick => "render_dir_partial();" %> Local Test 
    </div> <br />
    <%= form_tag({:controller => 'file_alias_validates', :action => 'file_dir', :method => :get}, {:id => 'dir_select_tag'}) do %>
    <div id="dir_list">
        <%= render :partial => 'dir_list', :locals => {:dir_choice => @radio_button_value } %> 
  </div><br />
  <% end %>
  <div id="list_files"> 
       <label for="file_list">Select Test File:</label> 
       <label>Dir Selected Path Value: </label><%= @selected_dir_list %>
       <%= render :partial => 'list_files', :locals => {:dir_path_choice => @dir_path_choice } %>   
  </div><br />
  <div    
    <table>         
        Select Test File:   
<!--  Production MiniProd Mounted Watchfolder (Both A3P and A4P Aspera folders in one read location.) -->           
        <% @files = Dir.glob("/watchfolder/miniprod/hot/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map %>
        <%= select_tag 'filepath2', options_for_select(@files, @selected_filepath) %> 
    </table>
  </div><br />
  </fieldset>
  <div id="holder" style="width:100%">
    <% if @file_exists_flag == 'N' %>   
        <div id="leftValidate"   style="float:left; width:50%">
        </p>
        <p><%= button_tag "Validate File Alias", :type => "submit" %></p>  
        </div>
        <div id="save_btn" style="float:right; width:50%">
        <p><%= button_tag "Save File Alias", :type => "submit" %></p>   
        </div>
    <% elsif @file_exists_flag == 'Y' %>
        <div id="leftValidate"   style="float:left; width:50%">
        </p>
        <p><%= button_tag "Validate File Alias", :type => "submit" %></p>  
        </div>
        <div id="update_btn" style="float:right; width:50%">
        <p><%= button_tag "Update File Alias", :type => "submit" %></p>     
        </div>
    <% else %>  
        <div id="leftValidate"   style="float:left; width:100%">
        </p>
        <p><%= button_tag "Validate File Alias", :type => "submit" %></p>  
        </div>
    <% end %>   
  </div>
<% end %>
<body>
    <% if @file_exists_flag == 'Y' %>
       <span style="color:green;font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; "><%=    @file_exists_msg %></span>
    <% elsif @file_exists_flag == 'N' %>
        <span style="color:red;font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; "><%=    @file_exists_msg %></span>
    <% else %>
       <% @file_exists_msg %>
    <% end %>   
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Alias Validation Results:</legend>
      <% if @state == "post" %>
          <pre>
            <label> Alias Generator Version:  </label> <%= @aliasgen_ver %>
                  <label> Alias: </label>  <%= @file_alias %> 
                <% if @file_status == ["F"] %>
                       <%= 'Validation Status:   '%><span style="color:green;font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; "><%= 'Success!' %> </span>
                <% else %>
                       <%= 'Validation Status:   '%><span style="color:red;font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; "><%= 'Failed!' %> </span>
               <%= 'Error Message:  ' %> <%= @file_msg %>
           <%= 'Closest Video Alias Match:  ' %> <%= @msg_dtl1 %>
           <%= 'Closest Audio Alias Match:  ' %> <%= @msg_dtl2 %>
                <% end %>               
                <!-- <%= @alias_xml_for %> --> 
          </pre>
      <% end %>   
  </fieldset><br />
</body> 
  <fieldset>
        <legend>Media Info File and Video Values:</legend>
          <% if @state == "post" %>
            <pre>
<%= 'File and Path: ' %> <%= @filepathname %> <br />
                <%= '======================================================' %>
                <%= '=                Video Specifications                =' %>
                <%= '======================================================' %>
                  <%= 'Video Format: ' %> <%= @video_format %> 
                <%= 'Video Bit Rate: ' %> <%= @video_bitrate %>  
                   <%= 'Video Width: ' %> <%= @video_width %> 
                  <%= 'Video Height: ' %> <%= @video_height %>   
              <%= 'Video Frame Rate: ' %> <%= @video_framerate %>  
                <%= 'Video Aspect Ratio: ' %> <%= @video_aspectratio %>  
                   <%= 'Video Scan Type: ' %> <%= @video_scantype %>  
                  <%= 'Video Scan Order: ' %> <%= @video_scanorder %>           
                <!-- <%= @media_xml_for %> --> 
            </pre>
          <% end %>     
  </fieldset><br /> 
</body>     

  <fieldset>
        <legend>Media Info XML:</legend>
          <% if @state == "post" %>
            <pre>
                <%= @media_xml_for %>
            </pre>
          <% end %>     
  </fieldset><br /> 

</body>


<script>
function render_dir_partial() {
    alert('in javascript.');
    alert("you chose the option: " + $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val() );
    radio_button_value = $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    alert ("radio_button_value: " + radio_button_value );
    if (radio_button_value == 'miniprod') {
        $('#dir_list').html('<%=j render :partial => "dir_list", :locals => { :dir_choice => 'miniprod' } %>')  
    } else if (radio_button_value == 'watch') {
        $('#dir_list').html('<%=j render :partial => "dir_list", :locals => { :dir_choice => 'watch' } %>') 
    } else if (radio_button_value == 'archive') {
        $('#dir_list').html('<%=j render :partial => "dir_list", :locals => { :dir_choice => 'archive' } %>')   
    } else if (radio_button_value == 'local') {
        $('#dir_list').html('<%=j render :partial => "dir_list", :locals => { :dir_choice => 'local' } %>') 
    } else {
        $('#dir_list').html('<%=j render :partial => "dir_list", :locals => { :dir_choice => '' } %>')  
    }
}
</script>
```

Here is the first 'dir_list' partial code:

```
   <div> 
        <label>Select Directory Path:</label><br />
        <label>Dir_Choice: </label><%= dir_choice %>
        <% if dir_choice== "miniprod" %> 
            <% @dir_list = Dir["/watchfolder/miniprod/*"] %>               
        <% elsif dir_choice== "watch" %> 
                <% @dir_list = Dir["/watchfolder/*"].reject{ |f| f[%r{^/watchfolder/miniprod}] || f[%r{^/watchfolder/aspera_console}]} %>  
        <% elsif dir_choice== "archive" %> 
              <% @dir_list = Dir["/archive/*"] %> 
        <% elsif dir_choice== 'local'%> 
              <% @dir_list = Dir["/home/silver/test/*"] %>  
        <% else  %> 
          <% @dir_list = ["/watchfolder/aspera_console/"] %>  
        <% end %>
        <%= select_tag 'dir_list', options_for_select(@dir_list, @selected_dir_list), :onchange => "this.form.submit();", :with => "'dir_list='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value", :remote => true  %>  
  </div>
```

Here is the 2nd dropdown box partial 'list_files'. (Note: the @files directory is hardcoded rightnow as I don't know how to get the @dir interpolated correctly).  The #{@dir} doesn't work in embedded Ruby.  I tried the erb template, then I got error "cannot convert nil to string".

```
 require 'erb'
  <p>          
        <label>Select Partial Test File:</label><br />
        <label>Dir Partial Selected Path Choice: </label><%= dir_path_choice %><br />
        <%= @dir_path_choice = params[:dir_list] %>
        <label>Partial Path Choice: </label><%= @dir_path_choice %><br />
        <% if @dir_path_choice %>
            <% @dir = 'Dir.glob("' << @dir_path_choice << '/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map' %>
        <% else %>
        <% @dir = 'Dir.glob('"/watchfolder/miniprod/hot/**/*.{mpg,mov}"').map' %>
        <% end %>   
        <label>Partial Dir: </label><%= @dir %><br />
        <% @files = Dir.glob("/watchfolder/showtimevod/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map %>
        <%= select_tag 'filepath', options_for_select(@files, @selected_filepath) %> 
  </p>
```

Here is my layout application.html:
(I have jquery in there from one of the tutorials. Please let me know if I need it or not.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CpOneOffd</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery','application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

NOTE:  I do have the file select box twice for now.  I left my old hard coded version in with the `<table>` tag and then added the dynamic partial above it to test with until I can get it to work. Please don't let the 2 confuse you in reviewing my code.

There is a validate file alias button.  Once the user selects the file, they then click the validate file alias and it calls the evaluate media method with call 2 library files. One that runs a media info and gets XML and then it passes the XML to a custom code that determines and inhouse alias. It reloads the page with the URL now for evaluate_media and all the media data showing.

When I select the directory, on change, the evaluate media shows up.  It does show that my selected value is getting passed correctly in the display screen.  I just don't have it dynamically reading the files yet. (My second code issue).  You will also notice I will be adding a save button and update button to save the data displayed for the file to a table.

UI Snapshots:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever gotten any ajax request to work?  If not, why would you attempt an ajax request in a complicated setting to learn how to make ajax requests?  Instead, you should start off by creating a controller with an index.html.erb page that simply displays 'Hello world".  Then add a button to the page, and add some jQuery to the page that sends an ajax get request when you click the button.  When an ajax request is received by the index controller, `if request.xhr?`, make the index controller respond with the string "Goodbye".  Then have your jQuery alert() the string.   Once you get that working, then have jQuery replace "Hello world" with the string returned by the index action, i.e. "Goodbye".

Once you get something simple like that to work, you might gain a better understanding of how jQuery and ajax requests work.  You should also employ something like Firefox + Firebug to examine the request and response and track any javascript errors.

The next step would be to put a select in index.html.erb, and try to write some jQuery that onchange sends an ajax request to index.html.erb, which in response to an ajax request sends back the String "I received the selection: 'server1'", and then insert that on the page after the select.

As for your current project:

1) This code:

```
<label for="dir_location">Select File Location:</label>
<br><%= radio_button_tag(
       'location', 
       'miniprod', 
       checked = true,         
       :onclick => "render_dir_partial();"
) %> MiniProd Watch Folder
```

will produce the html:

```
<input checked="checked" id="location_miniprod" name="location" onclick="render_dir_partial();" type="radio" value="miniprod" /> MiniProd Watch Folder
```

And putting javascript inside html tags is considered bad practice.  Good practice is to keep the javascript and the html separate.  You do that by using jQuery to select the radio buttons and add onclick event handlers to them. In addition:

> Always use labels for checkbox and radio buttons. They associate text
>   with a specific option and, by expanding the clickable region, make it
>   easier for users to click their [choice].

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

For instance:

```
<%= radio_button_tag('location', 'miniprod') %>
<%= label_tag('location_miniprod', 'MiniProd Watch Folder') %>
```

Also, what if the user wants to choose the first server?  In your code, it's checked by default, therefore to get the onclick event to fire for the first server, the user has to click on another server, then click on the first server.  It seems to me, you should leave all the radio buttons unchecked so that the user must click a server to choose it.

2)

> At this point I started to use form_tag and submit on change. It semi
>   works but because I have a master form url call for button click I run
>   into issues.

What is "a master form url call for button click"?  Does that mean you attached an onclick event handler to the form tag?  If so, you can prevent events from *bubbling* up to parent tags.  In jQuery, all event handler functions are passed the event object as an argument, and to stop the event from bubbling up to a parent element, you write:

```
function(event) {
  ...
  event.stopPropagation;
}
```

3) All these lines:

```
@aliasgen_ver = REXML::XPath.each(alias_parse_doc, "/aliasGenerator vr=/text()") { |element| element }
```

Can be replaced by:

```
@aliasgen_ver = REXML::XPath.match(alias_parse_doc, "/aliasGenerator vr=/text()")
```

You don't iterate over a collection in order to obtain the collection. What you are doing is equivalent to writing:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3].each {|num| num }
```

Because each() returns its receiver, [1, 2, 3] ends up being assigned to arr. But you can just write:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
```

Yes, the REXML tutorial sucks--the first thing it should show you is how to get an array of matching elements.  Also, REXML is old and slow.  Nokogiri is what people use now because it can do more things and it's fast.

4)

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which  
// will include all the files listed below.
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

In other words, all the mentioned files will be crammed into application.js, therefore if you have a script tag that links to application.js, you get everything in those files, hence this line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery','application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

specifies one too many files to link to.

5) All this code:

```
   <% if dir_choice== "miniprod" %> 
        <% @dir_list = Dir["/watchfolder/miniprod/*"] %>               
    <% elsif dir_choice== "watch" %> 
            <% @dir_list = Dir["/watchfolder/*"].reject{ |f| f[%r{^/watchfolder/miniprod}] || f[%r{^/watchfolder/aspera_console}]} %>  
    <% elsif dir_choice== "archive" %> 
          <% @dir_list = Dir["/archive/*"] %> 
    <% elsif dir_choice== 'local'%> 
          <% @dir_list = Dir["/home/silver/test/*"] %>  
    <% else  %> 
      <% @dir_list = ["/watchfolder/aspera_console/"] %>  
    <% end %>
```

…has nothing to do with generating html--the code just sets the value of @variables--therefore it should be in a controller.

6)

> It reads the value, does some if/else logic and then renders the
>   partial page for the dir_list…

You have that exactly backwards.

A browser has no idea what a partial is.  When a request hits the index action, Rails converts the partial, an html.erb file, into pure html (and javascript) by executing the ruby code and filling in the page, then the pure html page is sent to your browser.  Then your browser executes the javascript if-else logic at the appropriate time.  You have to keep things straight in your mind when things execute.  When things get too complex, like with your code, you should try going through your templates and substituting hard coded values for the ruby variables to see if the resulting html file you end up with makes sense.  Here is what your index.html.eb file looks like after rails inserts the partial and rails is trying to execute the ruby code:

```
function render_dir_partial() {
    radio_button_value = <will be fetched when this js function executes>;  

    if (radio_button_value == 'miniprod') {
       $('#dir_list').html( ---+
                               |
                               | dir_choice = 'miniprod'  
                               |
                               V
   <div> 
        <label>Select Directory Path:</label><br />
        <label>Dir_Choice: </label>miniprod
                                                                   undefined!
            @dir_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']                               |
                                                                      V
        <%= select_tag 'dir_list', options_for_select(@dir_list, @selected_dir_list), :onchange => "this.form.submit();", :with => "'dir_list='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value", :remote => true  %>  
  </div>
```

In addition, a select_tag() does not have a :remote=>true option, nor does it have a :with option.  See the docs for select_tag() here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag

And any options not recognized by the select_tag() method will be used to create attributes in the html, like this:

```
<select remote="true" with="'dir_list='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" >
```

and those html attributes are meaningless.

Below is an example that does what you are trying to do.  Once the user selects the file from the file select, the user can hit submit to send all the data to the server(i.e. to whatever action is specified in the form's action attribute).  I don't think submitting the form onchange is such a good idea because what if the user chooses the wrong thing by accident?

app/controllers/file_controller.rb:

```
class FileController < ApplicationController  

  def index
    if request.xhr?
      #Use params[:server] and params[:dir] to retrieve whatever files you want
      server = params[:server]
      dir = params[:dir]
      puts "***#{server}" #Will be output to server window
      puts "***#{dir}"  

      retrieved_file_names = [
        "a (#{server}/#{dir})", 
        "b (#{server}/#{dir})", 
        "c (#{server}/#{dir})",
      ]

      render partial: 'select', locals: {file_names: retrieved_file_names}

    else

      @servers = %w[ miniprod watch archive local ].each
      @radio_labels =  [
        "MiniProd Watch Folder",
        "Prod Watch Folder",
        "Prod Archive Folder",
        "Local Test",
      ].each

      @miniprod_dirs = ['miniprod_dir1', 'miniproddir2']
      @watch_dirs = ['watch_dir1', 'watch_dir2', 'watch_dir3']
      @archive_dirs = ['archive_dir1', 'archive_dir2', 'archive_dir3']
      @local_dirs = ['local_dir1', 'local_dir2', 'local_dir3']
    end

    #By default, renders 'views/file/index.html.erb'
  end

end
```

Here is the form produced by index.html.erb:

```
<form id="file_form" action="some_controller/some_action" method="post">

  <div>
    <input id="location_miniprod" name="location" type="radio" value="miniprod" />
    <label for="location_miniprod">MiniProd Watch Folder</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="location_watch" name="location" type="radio" value="watch" />
    <label for="location_watch">Prod Watch Folder</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="location_archive" name="location" type="radio" value="archive" />
    <label for="location_archive">Prod Archive Folder</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="location_local" name="location" type="radio" value="local" />
    <label for="location_local">Local Test</label>
  </div>


  <div id='dirs_div'></div>
  <div id='files_div'></div>

  <div><button type="submit">Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

index.html.erb:

```
<h1>File#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/file/index.html.erb</p>

<form id="file_form" action="some_controller/some_action" method="post">

<% 
loop do
  server = @servers.next
  radio_label = @radio_labels.next
%>
  <div>
    <%= 
      radio_button_tag(
        name = 'location', 
        value = server, 
        #checked = (server == 'miniprod')
      )
    %>
    <%=
      label_tag(name="location_#{server}", content=radio_label) 
    %>
  </div>

<% end %>

  <div id='dirs_div'></div>
  <div id='files_div'></div>

  <div><button type="submit">Submit</button></div>
</form>

<script>
function create_select(server_choice) {

  var dirs_for = {
    miniprod: <%= raw @miniprod_dirs %>,  //raw() somehow converts ruby arrays to js arrays
    watch: <%= raw @watch_dirs %>,
    archive: <%= raw @archive_dirs %>,
    local: <%= raw @local_dirs %>
  }
  var dirs = dirs_for[server_choice];

  var $new_select = $('<select id="directory" name="directory">');
  var options = [];

  //Create option that says 'select directory':
  options.push(
    $("<option>", {selected: "selected", disabled: "disabled", text: "select directory"})
  );

  var i;
  var len = dirs.length;
  var dir_name;

  for(i=0; i< len; i++) {
    dir_name = dirs[i];
    options.push( 
      $("<option>", {value: dir_name, text: dir_name} )
    );
  }

  $new_select.append(options);

  $new_select.on("change", function() {
    var dir_choice = $(this).val()

    //Here's the ajax request:
    $.get(
      '/file/index', 
      {server: server_choice, dir: dir_choice}, 
      function(select_html) { $("#files_div").html(select_html) },
      'html'
    );

  });

  $('#dirs_div').html($new_select);
  //In addition, when a new server is chosen, the file select,
  //if it is already being displayed, should be deleted.
  $('#files_div').empty()  
}


//Add an onclick event handler to each of the radio buttons:
$('input[name=location]', '#file_form').on('click', function(event) {
  var server_choice = $(this).val()
  create_select(server_choice);
  event.stopPropagation();  //Prevent click event from 'bubbling' up to parent tags
});

</script>
```

app/views/file/_select.html.erb:

```
<%=
prompt = 'select file'

select_tag( 
  name = 'file',  
  options_for_select(
    file_names.unshift(prompt),  //Add prompt to the front of the Array
    selected: prompt,
    disabled: prompt,
  )
) 
%>
```